# Fitting cubic polynomial coefficients with GridSearchCV

Tags: scikit-learn, curve-fitting, hyperparameters, model-fitting, gridsearchcv

I have a cubic polynomial, with known coefficients a, b, c & d.

I would like to write an algorithm that finds these coefficients based on a set of supplied x and corresponding y coordinates along the curve.

This seems like a very simple case of parameter tuning. I'd like to specify a range of possible values, and have GridSearchCV iterate through all the combinations, score the outcome and recommend the combination of values with the highest score (or lowest cost function).

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV


def poly(x,a=1,b=1,c=1,d=1):
    
    """A polynomial function that calculates a polynomial function for an array of x values
    a, b, c & d are the coefficients of the polynomial"""
    
    y = a*x**3 + b*x**2 + c*x + d
    
    return y

# Regular values along the x axis
x_range = np.arange(-10,11,1)

# The 'true' coefficients
a_t = 0.1; b_t = -0.5; c_t = 0.8; d_t = 10

# Y values of the 'true' polynomial along the x axis
y_true = poly(x_range, a_t,b_t,c_t,d_t)


######## Fit the parameters ########

model = poly(x=x_range)

# define a grid of parameters to sort through 

param_grid={
    'a' : [0,0.1,0.2],
    'b' : [-1,-0.5,0,0.5,1],
    'c' : [1,2],
    'd' : [0,10,20,30]}

grid = GridSearchCV(model, param_grid=param_grid, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')

grid.fit(x_range, y_true)
```

I'm getting the error: "TypeError: estimator should be an estimator implementing 'fit' method, array([-909, -656, -455, -300, -185, -104,  -51,  -20,   -5,    0,    1,
4,   15,   40,   85,  156,  259,  400,  585,  820, 1111]) was passed"

I'd like to know what I need to supply to the grid.fit function to make it iterate through the param_grid and find the combination of parameters with the highest score, based on the supplied y_true values.

Comment: The error is because you are passing an array (the output of `poly`) into `GridSearchCV` whereas it is expecting a scikit estimator such as `sklearn.svm.SVC()`. Is it possible to clarify why you want to use `GridSearchCV` to get the coefficients rather than a regression model? In the setup you are using there aren't any free parameters for the training of the estimator. If you just have the 4 coefficients to estimate then regression could suffice unless your question is part of a bigger model you are working on?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that GridSearchCV was not the correct tool for my requirement. Thanks to balleveryday for the insightful comment.

I should have been using the scipy.optimize library. Below are two solutions using the optimize.curve_fit and optimize.minimise modules:

Essential code for both:

```
import numpy as np
import math

def poly(x,a,b,c,d):
    
    """A polynomial function that calculates y values for an array of x values.
    a, b, c & d are the coefficients of the polynomial"""
    
    y = a*x**3 + b*x**2 + c*x + d
    
    return y

# Regular values along the x axis
x_range = np.arange(-10,11,1)

# The 'true' coefficients
a_t = 0.1; b_t = -0.5; c_t = math.pi/3; d_t = math.pi*2

# Y values of the 'true' polynomial along the x axis
y_true = poly(x_range, a_t,b_t,c_t,d_t)

bounds = np.array( [(0,1), (-2,2), (-3,3), (0,20)] )

initial_guess = np.array([0.5,-1, 1.2, 10])
```

`curve_fit` solution:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

popt, pcov = curve_fit(poly, x_range, y_true, p0 = initial_guess, bounds = bounds.T)

print(popt)
```

`minimize` solution with two different minimization methods:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def cost_fn(guess_array,true_array):
    
    diff = guess_array - true_array
    min_quad = np.mean(diff**4)
    
    return(min_quad)


def calculate_cost(params):
    
    y_trial = poly(x_range, a=params[0], b= params[1], c=params[2], d=params[3])
    
    cost = cost_fn(y_trial,y_true)
    
    return(cost)

for method in ['Powell', 'L-BFGS-B']:
    res = minimize(fun = calculate_cost, 
                   x0 = initial_guess,
                   bounds = bounds,
                   method = method,
                  )

    print(res.x)
```